# Counter to victory in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, counter

have been having a problem while working in Unity. I simply want to increase a score every time a collision is made, but my code just isn't helping. I know it sounds basic but I've been looking around in the site for quite some time now and I haven't found an answer yet.
Here's the script:

I have already checked and the "VictoryScreen" is already made and built.

```
public class PaintScriptGreen : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject CylGreen;

    private int score = 0;

    private Vector3 tempPos;

    private Quaternion tempRot;

    private GameObject tempCyl;

    void Awake () 
    {

    }

    public void AddScore (int scoreValue)
    {
            score += scoreValue;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Cylinder" && col.gameObject.tag != "TreeHolder") 
        {
            tempPos = col.gameObject.transform.position;
            tempRot = col.gameObject.transform.rotation;
            Destroy (col.gameObject);
            tempCyl = Instantiate(CylGreen, tempPos, tempRot) as GameObject;
            AddScore (1);
            if (score >= 4)
            {
                Application.LoadLevel ("VictoryScreen");
            }
        }

        if ((col.gameObject.tag != "Player")&&(col.gameObject.tag != "PlayPart")) 
        {
                // destroy self bullet
                Destroy (this.gameObject);
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what doesn't work and what do you expect as an answer. Could you tell us more ? Also you say "each time a collision is made", trigger and collision are not the same. Are you sure it's what you want to do ?

Comment: I think it's a trigger, sorry, I'm kinda new to Unity. The thing is, the score variable is always at 0, or it appears so, because the screen never changes, even through the triggers work (everything else associated to the trigger happens in the game itself. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Did you try to display your score variable using Debug.Log to be sure of it's value (after AddScore and after the increment in AddScore) ?

Comment: The value isn't being modified, I already did that, and that is the problem. If I set the required value to advance to 1, the screen changes just right, but any value over that ends up presenting trouble. It's like the value is resetting every time the trigger happens.

Comment: Have you only one object using PaintScriptGreen ? It's not a generated one or something ? (sorry for the dumb questions but the code is correct so it should be Unity-related)

Comment: By that question I think I just realized the answer to my problem, let me test it!!

Comment: Dont forget to post your solution as an answer if you think it could help someone :)

Comment: It didn't work ): 
When PaintScriptGreen runs it "paints" a shape by deleting an object and placing a new one with the same dimensions over it, and it runs whenever a sphere thrown by the player "collisions" with the object, and this is done a lot of times.

Comment: Hey can you try to do debug.log(score) inside and out the if statement ? And are you sure that the code in the ontrigger is being implemented ? And do you have application.load() anywhere else in scripts?

Comment: is this script attached to the gameObjects being instantiated/destroyed? I'm wondering if the Debug.Log output is actually from different objects. I.e. score is 0, score is 1 from addscore, object destroyed, new object instantiated with default score of 0... score is 0 (rinse, repeat), maybe a `Debug.Log(gameObject.name + " " + score)` would be helpful

Comment: The problem was that the script was attached to a gameObject that was being destroyed all the time (The "bullets"), so after changing that everything was solver :) Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

```
    if ((col.gameObject.tag != "Player")&&(col.gameObject.tag != "PlayPart")) 
    {
            // destroy self bullet
            Destroy (this.gameObject);
    }
```

This is probably the culprit. You're destroying "this" anytime the above conditions aren't true. Is this script on the bullet? If so, you'll need to move the scoring mechanism to an object that isn't getting destroyed OR make it a static variable. I don't like static variables, but it is a possible solution.